# Downgrading from "Java for OS X Lion Update 1"

Tags: macos, java

I recently ran Software Update and installed "Update 1" for Java for Lion. Unfortunately this broke about the only thing I use Java for - a webcam applet to check conditions at a ski area. The applet hangs Safari until I close the tab and force quit the process, and in Chrome it simply displays the Java Applet loading screen with no progress.

So, the questions:

1. How can I remove this update?
2. Where can I get the original version? The only download link I can find now leads to the updated version.

Comment: Can you give example link to check if Java Developer Package for Mac OS X 10.7 Update 1 package is also broken or not?

Comment: Haven't tried your solution yet, but this is the page that hangs Safari for me: http://www.craigleith.com/site/index.cfm?DSP=Section&ID=10

Comment: I see endless loading or white blank space (Safari & recent Opera 11.60) with no errors in console and Oracle VisualVM.

Comment: I've got [error](http://pastebin.com/X3fHYkqN)! Probably it's server-side problem

Comment: same for my Windows machine. no luck to download classes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where to find original version of Java for Mac OS Lion.

At least you can [download](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Java/java_for_mac_os_x_10.7_developer_package/javadeveloper_for_mac_os_x_10.7__11a511.dmg) *Java Developer Package for Mac OS X 10.7* with your AppleID or [try](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/java_for_mac_os_x_10.7_update_1_developer_package/javadeveloper_for_mac_os_x_10.7__11m3527.dmg) *Java Developer Package for Mac OS X 10.7 Update 1* package to be sure if this bug is here.

Tutorials how to downgrade your Java you can find [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/36508/can-you-downgrade-java-on-a-mac) and [here](http://www.servoymagazine.com/home/2010/06/tutorials-how-to-downgrade-java-on-a-mac.html).

Comment: Thanks. Gave this a try with the first developer package, but it seems the bug is still there. Perhaps it's not directly related to the update.